# AWS RDS MySQL How can I change table_cache option?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to set `table_cache` option, however, I cannot find `table_cache` in RDS parameters. Where can I change this option?

Thank you.

Comment: which engine/version? maybe youre looking for table_open_cache?

Comment: @at0mzk I am using MySQL 5.6.27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `table_cache` system variable was deprecated and renamed `table_open_cache` back in MySQL 5.1, and was still called `table_open_cache` in [5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-cache.html).

It's in the RDS parameter group.

However, it's very rare that this value is an appropriate value to tweak.  It has long been known to [scale negatively](https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/11/16/table_cache-negative-scalability/) -- the more "optimum" your configuration, the worse the server will perform.

If you're using a tuning script, the odds are extremely high that you're operating on bad advice if changing that value has been recommended.  Tuning scripts in general are notorious for their well-intentioned, but ill-conceived, bad advice.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is `thread_cache` renamed to `thread_cache_size`? I cannot find `thread_cache` either.

Comment: I don't remember `thread_cache_size` formerly being called `thread_cache` but maybe.  [`thread_cache_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size) is the current name of the variable that determines the max number of surplus threads to cache.  Read [this answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45570/11651) -- particularly the blockquote excerpt about how *“Tuning” your server can be a stunning waste of time.*